# How can I add 'if' condition in laravel pagination which I used in foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-blade

**This below code is the controller code. Where my logic is there. Want to get those profiles that have no log**

```
    public function not_checked_yet() {
        $pageName = "Not Checked Profiles";
        $status = "Active";
        $treeView = "Clients";
        $groupbyActivation = $this->groupbyActivation();
        $adminSerchs = BbUser::select(['id', 'profile_id', 'user_profession', 'user_looking_for', 'user_profile_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_religion', 'present_district', 'country_of_residence', 'activation', 'membership_status'])
                        ->where('activation', 1)
                        ->where('membership_status', 107)
                        ->where('office_id', auth()->user()->agent_id)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate(5);  
        return view('agent.profile.search-result.not-check-search-result', compact('adminSerchs', 'pageName', 'groupbyActivation', 'status','treeView'));

    }
```

**This below code is the view blade code. Where I used an if condition in foreach loop. So, how can I use this if condition in my pagination also?**

```
@foreach ($adminSerchs as $key => $search_result)
   @php
     $none_check_log = \App\AgentsRemark::where('profile_id', 
     $search_result->profile_id)->count();
   @endphp
   @if($none_check_log < 1)
     <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>
       {{ $search_result->name }}
      </td>
   @endif
@endforeach
  {{ $adminSerchs->links() }}
```

Comment: You should use relationship with `BbUser` and `AgentsRemark` and add where condition in main query in controller itself instead of writing separate query in blade after generating result. also tell us what is the relationship with those models so we can help writing relationship query.

Comment: BbUser and AgentsRemark both have 'profile_id'. I want all the BbUser doesn't have any AgentsRemark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `BbUser.php` model and link with `hasMany` relationship.

```
public function agent_remarks(){
  return $this->hasMany(AgentsRemark::class,"profile_id","profile_id");
}
```

Now in your controller check the absence of a relationship `agent_remarks` using `doesntHave` so your query would be like below, and you don't need to use if condition in your blade file.

```
$adminSerchs = BbUser::doesntHave('agent_remarks')
                    ->select(['id', 'profile_id', 'user_profession', 'user_looking_for', 'user_profile_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_religion', 'present_district', 'country_of_residence', 'activation', 'membership_status'])
                    ->where('activation', 1)
                    ->where('membership_status', 107)
                    ->where('office_id', auth()->user()->agent_id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->paginate(5);
```

checkout for the detail understading on relationships : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 1):

If you define a `agentsRemarks` relationship on the `BbUser` model, you can use [`doesntHave`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) to get `BbUser`s who do not have any remarks.

What you'd need would be something like

```php
// BbUser.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class BbUser extends Model
{
    public function agentsRemarks(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AgentsRemark::class, 'profile_id', 'profile_id');
    }
}
```

And then in your controller, you can add a `->doesntHave('agentsRemarks')` condition. For example,

```php
public function not_checked_yet()
{
    $pageName = "Not Checked Profiles";
    $status = "Active";
    $treeView = "Clients";
    $groupbyActivation = $this->groupbyActivation();
    $adminSerchs = BbUser::select(['id', 'profile_id', 'user_profession', 'user_looking_for', 'user_profile_image', 'user_date_of_birth', 'user_religion', 'present_district', 'country_of_residence', 'activation', 'membership_status'])
        ->where('activation', 1)
        ->where('membership_status', 107)
        ->where('office_id', auth()->user()->agent_id)
        ->doesntHave('agentsRemarks')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(5);
    return view('agent.profile.search-result.not-check-search-result', compact('adminSerchs', 'pageName', 'groupbyActivation', 'status', 'treeView'));
}
```